# ElasticSearch find by name and return the cheapest

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, match

I have 'contract' type with following mapping:

```
{
  "contract" : {
    "properties" : {
      "active" : {
        "type" : "boolean"
      },
      [ ... ] 
      "device" : {
        "properties" : {
          [ ... ] 
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          [ ... ] 
        }
      },
      "handset_price" : {
        "type" : "double"
      },
      "id" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      },
      [ ... ] 
      "monthly_price" : {
        "type" : "double"
      },
      [ ... ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Now I need to get the cheapest deal (contract) for given device. This is what I have now:

```
{
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "device.title": device_name
            }
        },
        "size": 1,
        "sort":
            [
                {"monthly_price": {"order": "asc"}},
                {"handset_price": {"order": "asc"}}
        ]
    }
```

`device_name` is string (e.g. `Lumia 530`).

When I search for 'Samsung', I get cheapest Samsung Galaxy s3 Mini. The problem is that looking for 'Samsung Note' gives me Galaxy s3 again, instead of returning one of the existing samsung note deals.

Any clue as to what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you sort your results by price, which though doesn't take the relevance of your result into account.

When searching for "Samsung", as you sort by ascending price, you will always have the cheapest "Samsung Galaxy s3 Mini" as first result.

If you want to have your Samsung Note device first, you have to sort by score (default sorting).

If you want to sort by score, and then have, for each score value, the cheapest results as first results, add "_score" to your sorting, like this :

```
{
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "device.title": device_name
            }
        },
        "size": 1,
        "sort":
            [
                {"_score": {"order": "desc"}},
                {"monthly_price": {"order": "asc"}},
                {"handset_price": {"order": "asc"}}
        ]
    }
```

Using `min_score` isn't recommended, unless for some advanced cases, as stated in the [documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html). The score is a relative value, and setting an absolute threshold can lead to weird results.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by using default `OR` [operator](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#_boolean) in the `match` query, which in case of `Samsung Note` is finding the cheapest `Samsung` or `Note`. Switching to the `AND` operator will return only contracts that contain both `Samsung` and `Note`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "device.title": {
                "query": "Samsung Note",
                "operator": "and"

            }
        }
    },
    "size": 1,
    "sort":[
        {"monthly_price": {"order": "asc"}},
        {"handset_price": {"order": "asc"}}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

min_score removes documents with to low score.

```
{
        "query": {
            "match" : {
                "device.title" : {
                    "query" : device_name
                }
            }
        },
        "min_score": 1,
        "track_scores": True,
        "size": 1,
        "sort":
            [
                {"monthly_price": {"order": "asc"}},
                {"handset_price": {"order": "asc"}}
        ]
    }
```